# kernel 5.15.0-40 - out of memory - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block (0,0)

Tags: boot, kernel, 22.04

I know there are already a bunch of questions about this topic, but even after going through many of them I still haven't found a solution.

- When I try to boot into kernel 5.15.0-40 I get a `error: out of memory` message and the following trace.
- Booting into  5.15.0-39 is fine
- Weirdly enough, if I do `sudo apt reinstall linux-image-5.15.0-40-generic`, then then reboot, I can get into the new kernel **exactly once**. If I reboot a second time the error occurs again (tried this twice now).

Full error log (via google lens, so some typos possible):

```
0.589021] pci 0000:00:07.0: DPC: RP PIO log size 0 is invalid
0.591393] pci 0000:00:07.1: DPC: RP PIO log size 0 is invalid 0.7586641 Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block (0,0)
0.758683] CPU: 4 PID: 1 Comm: swapper/0 Not tainted 5.15.0-40-generic #43-Ubuntu
0.758699] Hardware name: Dell Inc. Precision 7560/0G01WF, BIOS 1.11.0 03/24/2022
0.758714] Call Trace:
0.758722]   <TASK>
0.758728]   show_stack+0x52/0x58 
0.758739]   dump_stack_lul+0x4a/0x5f
0.758749]   dump_stack+0x10/0x12
0.758757]   panic+0x149/0x321 
0.758766]   mount_block_root+0x144/0x1d9
0.758777]   mount_root+0x10c/0x118
0.758786]   prepare_namespace+0x13f/0x18d
0.758796]   kernel_init_freeable+0x18c/0x1b1
0.758809]   ? rest_init+0x100/0x100
0.758821]   kernel_init+0x1b/0x150
0.758829]   ? rest_init+0x100/0x100
0.758838]   ret_from_fork+0x1f/0x30
0.758848] </TASK>
0.758938] Kernel Offset: 0x16200000 from Oxffffffff81000000 (relocation range: 0xffffffff80000 
0.758961] ---[ end Kernel panic- not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block (0,0) ]---
```

Other things I tried already

- `dpkg --configure linux-image-5.15.0-40-generic`
- `update-initramfs` + `update-grub`
- making space on `/boot` by deleting all ZFS snapshots

I'm using 22.04 with encrypted ZFS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case it was caused by too large `initrd` files, which I was able to reduce from ~180MB to ~115MB by using this suggestion [Dell XPS 15 9550 - Ubuntu after upgrade(including Kernel) will not boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1349830/dell-xps-15-9550-ubuntu-after-upgradeincluding-kernel-will-not-boot/1412273#1412273), but with `xz` instead of `lz4` for even better compression.

```bash
ll /boot/initrd.img-5*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 159411790 Okt 27 10:16 /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-50-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 115170168 Okt 27 15:55 /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-52-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 159453565 Okt 27 13:39 /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-52-generic.old-dkms
```