# Ubuntu 21.04 able to boot after restart from windows only

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, ssd, 21.04

**Device details:**

- IdeaPad Gaming 3i
- Processor : AMD Ryzen 5 4600h with radeon graphic
- Graphics  : Nvidia GeForce GTX 1650 Ti Mobile
- 2 SSD M.2 NVME

I have dual boot Ubuntu 21.04 and Windows 10 on different SSD. **Windows 10 is on nvme0** and **Ubuntu on nvme1**. the EFI bootable for ubuntu is already isolated in Ubuntu ssd which is nvme1 and in the boot order already set first in bios menu.

**The Problem:**

I can't boot to the Ubuntu after I turn off the machine, either it's from Ubuntu or windows. What I means by turn off is shutdown (Power off on Ubuntu). What I get is just black screen with no text on it, no sound whatsoever. I can't go to tty by pressing ctrl+alt+f2 until f12, but I can press ctrl+alt+del which make me restart the machine back to the grub. I've tried edit the grub by pressing "e" on Ubuntu and edit the "quit splash" to "nosplash" or just delete them so I can see log text but it doesn't work, going to advance and boot from different kernel and safe mode also doesn't work.

Weirdly I can boot to the Ubuntu after I login to Windows and restart from there. The boot time after restart from Windows to Ubuntu is just few second.

**The similar problem I found on this website:**

- [Ubuntu only Boots after Booting Windows and Restarting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1075544/ubuntu-only-boots-after-booting-windows-and-restarting)
- [Need to restart from windows to boot into Ubuntu (dual boot)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1325825/need-to-restart-from-windows-to-boot-into-ubuntu-dual-boot)
- [Ubuntu 21.04 not booting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1343808/ubuntu-21-04-not-booting)

but none of the answer there really fix my problem

**The Error I frequently see in log and short period of time in boot to Ubuntu:**

```
[   0.004743] efi: Failed to lookup EFI memory descriptor for 0x00000000cb6be000    
[   0.572343] integrity: Problem loading X.509 certificate -65
```

and

```
blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev nvme1n1, sector 559166272 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
```

**What I Have Try to Fix it:**

- Disable **secure boot**
- Disable **fast boot on windows**
- Adjust the Ubuntu to boot first in bios
- Reinstal **Nvidia Driver**
- Add **modeset** to the grub menu (It just make it unbootable after restart from windows)
- Moving **efi Ubuntu boot UUID** to either nvme0 (Windows drive) and nvme1 (Ubuntu drive) (Nothing change)

none of the method above fix the problem

**What I Have not Try:**

- Disable fast boot on bios. But this option I can't really find in my bios, so I don't know.
- Unplug the drive containing Windows and only plug the Ubuntu one. But that just make it not dual boot.
- Reinstalling Ubuntu (please don't)